# VBA macro for Microsoft Word to remove the hyperlink (not the text) when the hyperlink contains a particular string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a VBA macro for Microsoft Word that will go through the hyperlinks and remove those that contain a particular string.

This is what I initially came up with:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveLinks()

    Dim Position As Integer
    Dim Hyperlink As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NumLinks As Integer
    Const ToFind As String = "ENREF"
    
    NumLinks = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks.Count
    For i = 1 To NumLinks
        Hyperlink = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks(i).SubAddress
        Position = InStr(1, Hyperlink, ToFind)
        If Position > 0 Then
            ThisDocument.Hyperlinks(i).Delete
            NumLinks = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks.Count
            i = 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

After some of the suggestions here, I also found out that the following code also works:

```
'VBA macro for Microsoft Word to remove the hyperlink (not the text) when the hyperlink contains a particular string
'Author: ARGYROU MINAS (minasargyrou@outlook.com)
'Licensed under the MIT License
'https://gist.github.com/04728af4c913f22bd35e65df3dddd43b.git
'
'Copyright 2023 ARGYROU MINAS
'
'Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the “Software”), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
'
'The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
'
'THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
'
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveLinksContainingInputString()

    Dim Position1 As Integer
    Dim Position2 As Integer
    Dim Hyperlink1 As String
    Dim Hyperlink2 As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NumLinks As Integer
    Dim ToFind As String
    
    ToFind = InputBox("Input the text to match within the hyperlinks.", "Text to match")
    NumLinks = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks.Count
    For i = NumLinks To 1 Step -1
        Hyperlink1 = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks(i).Address
        Hyperlink2 = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks(i).SubAddress
        Position1 = InStr(1, Hyperlink1, ToFind)
        Position2 = InStr(1, Hyperlink2, ToFind)
        If (Position1 > 0) Or (Position2 > 0) Then
            ThisDocument.Hyperlinks(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

From what I understand, the reverse loop seems to be faster and more efficient, since it avoids re-initialization. But, does the forward loop have any other drawbacks?

Will this code work properly? It seems to work but, just before it finishes running, I get the error that the requested member does not exist when using the forward loop; why is that?

Lastly, what is the difference between "Address" and "Subaddress"?

Comment: Nope. When you want to delete something inside a loop, loop backwards: `For i = NumLinks To 1 Step -1`.

Comment: @FunThomas Actually, it does seem to work. But, why do you recommend looping backwards?

Comment: @FunThomasSo, instead of doing the re-initialization that I do, you do the loop in reverse. Do the way that I did it have any drawbacks, other than being much slower?

Comment: When you loop through a collection to delete items you should always loop in reverse. This ensures that the index is always correct.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/04728af4c913f22bd35e65df3dddd43b.git

Answer (score 1):

It seams there are some problems with your code. Please follow as bellow

```
    NumLinks = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks.Count
For i = NumLinks To 1 'reverse the loop(upto 1 not 0) as you wish to delete the link
    Hyperlink = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks(i).Address 'Remove Items here
    Position = InStr(1, Hyperlink, ToFind)
    If Position > 0 Then
        ThisDocument.Hyperlinks(i).Delete
        'Remove this =>NumLinks = ThisDocument.Hyperlinks.Count
        'Remove this =>i = 0
    End If
Next i
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the response. While you were writing your answer, I had already edited the code. The reason I used the NumLinks= and i=1 in the loop is because, I believed that after removing a hyperlink, the numbering would change and a new Count would be require. Lastly, as another commenter mentioned, too, why do the loop in reverse?

Comment: So you do not have to re initialize the loop to run again from beginning.

Comment: @Yeah, you are correct. So, instead of doing the re-initialization that I do, you do the loop in reverse. Do the way that I did it have any drawbacks, other than being much slower?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `For i = NumLinks To 1 Step -1`